# Generating absolute URLs from Seam emails

Tags: java, email, url, jsf, seam

Is there a way to coax either the `h:outputLink` or `s:link` tags into generating absolute URLs?  In a Seam email message, I want to be able to do something like

```
<s:link view="/someView.xhtml">
    <f:param name="a" value="#{a.nastyParam}" />
    <f:param name="b" value="#{b.nastyParam}" />
    <h:outputText value="Come do something awesome!" />
</s:link>
```

and generate an absolute URL without the fuss of messing with URL encoding, prepending the protocol, host, context path, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind... I should have looked more closely at my copy of "Seam in Action" before asking this one.  Setting the `urlBase` attribute on the `m:message` tag did the trick.